# Does God in Hinduism have foreknowledge of everything?

Tags: gods, free-will

If yes, wouldn't that mean no one except God has free will?

Comment: one has an illusion of freewill within the sphere of  influence incited by one's own  personality laden with pastlives experience , conditioning  environment karma so on. so says Gita 3.28 *guna guneshu vartante iti matva na sajjate* . God has the foreknowledge/triple time vision as  said in Gita 7.26 *vedaham samatitani..* which is beyond all intellectual reasoning /analysis.

Comment: What is "God", singular?